# Instantiate Show typeclass for a custom NestedList type

Tags: haskell

I have defined the following custom type of arbitrary deep lists

```
data NestedList a
    = Elem a
    | List [NestedList a]
```

and I want to instantiate Show and pretty print my nested lists, but I don't have any idea about how the show function should look for my type

```
instance (Show a) => Show (NestedList a) where
```

for example if we have

```
let a = List [List[Elem 2], Elem 1, List[Elem 1, Elem 2],
              List[List[Elem 2, Elem 3]], Elem 5]
```

I want `show a` to print

```
"[[2], 1, [1, 2], [[2, 3]], 5]"
```

How can I implement the `show` function?

Comment: You have the right signature for your `Show` instance. What have you tried for the implementation?

Comment: I think this is pretty straightforward - just pattern-match on your 2 constructors, and use recursion for the `List` one. The [intersperse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse) function should be useful for the recursive case.

Comment: I am pretty noob in thinking functionally. I don't manage to find a rule. Now I'm playing with show (Elem a) = show a ++ ", "
    show (List (x:xs)) = "[" ++ show x ++ "]" ++ (concat (fmap show xs))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the instance you want:

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]

instance (Show a) => Show (NestedList a) where
    show (Elem a) = show a
    show (List xs) = "[" ++ intercalate ", " (map show xs) ++ "]"
```

Note that you will need to import `intercalate` from `Data.List`. (This is different from `intersperse` which I mentioned in my comment - apologies that in haste I picked the wrong one.)

I hope this makes sense when you've seen it - we simply borrow the `show` instance for `a` to treat the `Elem a` case. Then the `List` case displays all the elements, puts the string `", "` between each, and encloses the whole in square brackets.

Proof that it works on your example:

```
Prelude Data.List> :{
Prelude Data.List| let a = List [List[Elem 2], Elem 1, List[Elem 1, Elem 2],
Prelude Data.List|               List[List[Elem 2, Elem 3]], Elem 5]
Prelude Data.List| :}
Prelude Data.List> a
[[2], 1, [1, 2], [[2, 3]], 5]
```

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid good point. I can't try it right now but that could well work :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to implement Show, just ask the compiler to derive it:

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
deriving Show
```

The Show typeclass is typically reserved for printing values in a format that can be read back by the language.

> Derived instances of Show have the following properties, which are compatible with derived instances of Text.Read.Read: * The result of show is a syntactically correct Haskell expression containing only constants, given the fixity declarations in force at the point where the type is declared. It contains only the constructor names defined in the data type, parentheses, and spaces. When labelled constructor fields are used, braces, commas, field names, and equal signs are also used.

By convention, your function should be defined separately from the Show typeclass instance.

Comment: While this works if all you want is *an* instance, OP was pretty specific about how they wanted the output to look, so the automatically-derived instance does not suffice in this case.

Comment: yes, but this will just print the standard constructors. I want a custom show method to pretty print the NestedList

Comment: Your quote is only about derived (i.e. automatically generated) instances of `Show`. Nothing is said or implied about manually written instances.

Comment: Manual instances are usually reserved for cases where it is meaningless to actually show the data. Think of a widget in a graphical toolkit, for instance. It has long been convention to use Show to convert data to a machine representation. Hijacking Show to make your data pretend to look like actual Haskell strings is counter-intuitive and will confuse other users. It's not impossible to do so, it might just not be in the interests of OP.